# Java - How can I convert throwable to a new throwable and throw it?

Tags: java, rx-java

When an exception occurs and I get Throwable I want to convert it to MyThrowable and re-throw it.

I am implementing a method on the instance creation

```
   obs1 = obs1.map(new Func1<Integer, Integer>() {
            public Integer call(Integer integer) {
             try {
                    getObj().equals(""); // an exception occurs
                    return ++integer;
                } catch (Throwable t) {
//                    t = new MyThroawable("",""); // if this is unmarked - failes to compile
                    throw t;
                }
            }
        });
```

- I need to deal with Throwable because my reactive fw (rxJava) returns a throwable on error

Compilation error I get when remark is moved from the new Throwable creation is

```
java: unreported exception async.job.MyThroawable; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: edited with the message

Answer (score 4):

Generally, you should avoid throwing exceptions from FuncX and ActionX instances and you can't throw checked exceptions directly.

However, if you want map over an API which throws a checked exception, you can use `flatMap` where you either return a regular value observable or an error observable:

```
source.flatMap(integer -> {
    try {
        getObj().equals("")
        return Observable.just(++integer);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        return Observable.error(OnErrorThrowable.addValueAsLastCause(t, integer));
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use exception chaining:

```
} catch (Throwable t) {
     throw new MyThroawable("Something failed", t);
}
```

You should also [include useful information in your message](http://blog.pdark.de/2009/01/30/a-different-view-on-exceptions-2/) that will help to determine what went wrong (like the object on which you were working).

> java: unreported exception async.job.MyThroawable

Java doesn't allow you to throw checked exceptions without declaring them. This is an [old debate](http://blog.pdark.de/2007/06/29/whats-wrong-with-exceptions/).

The fix is to add `throws MyThroawable` to the method (and then fix the hundreds of compile errors that you'll get elsewhere) or make `MyThroawable` extend `RuntimeException` (recommended).

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two throw statements one after the other.

Just throw your custom exception:

```
     public Integer call(Integer integer) throws MyThroawable 
     {
         try {
             getObj().equals(""); // an exception occurs
             return ++integer;
         } catch (Throwable t) {
             throw new MyThroawable("","");
         }
     }
```

You might want to pass the original Throwable `t` to your custom exception's constructor.

In addition, if `MyThrowable` is a checked exception, you must add a throws clause to your `public Integer call(Integer integer)` method.

Comment: Thanks. I have written the other throw just to show that it compiles. when I try to change the t it doesn't.

Comment: I can't add a checked exception because it is a third party class.
I just want to send a custom throwable.

Comment: sending the original t as a parameter is a good practice but it still does not compile.

Comment: java: unreported exception async.job.MyThroawable; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Comment: @rails This error means MyThroawable is a checked exception. As I was saying, you must add a throws clause in order for that method to be able to throw a checked exception. If you can't add a throws clause, you can't throw that exception.

Answer (score 0):

I guess yoour Throwable extends Throwable :). One of the constructors of Throwable class (which your class should also have) is one that receives another Throwable exception. So you just do:

throw new MyThrowable( t );

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that every Throwable that a method can throw (except for [RuntimeExceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html?is-external=true) must be declared in the method declaration using the `throws` keyword. So the ideal way would be to change

```
public Integer call(Integer integer) { ...
```

to

```
public Integer call(Integer integer) throws MyThrowable  { ...
```

However, since this method is not defined in `Func1`, you would get an error stating `overridden method does not throw Exception`. Thus, your best bet would probably be to use a closure, i.e., declare some variable outside your `call`-function, store the exception there and rethrow it outside of the call to `map`. This would look something like this:

```
Throwable t = null;

obs1 = obs1.map(new Func1<Integer, Integer>() {
  public Integer call(Integer integer) {
    try { ... }
    catch (Throwable t) { outerThrowable = t; }
  }
});

if(t != null) {
  throw new MyThroawable("", "");
}
```

Just remember to declare `throws MyThrowable` in the surrounding method, otherwise you will get the same error there.

---

**Edit:** As Aaron pointed out, it would also be possible to let `MyThrowable` extend `RuntimeException` instead of `Throwable`. In this case, you could just rethrow them directly in the `map`-function. However, you would have to document this somewhere in order to not surprise the callers of your method if it suddenly throws an exception. This is vey much a design choice, so you have to decide.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using RxJava, you may use an RxJava exception which keep the value which throw the exception :

```
throw OnErrorThrowable.addValueAsLastCause(e, file);
```

So in your code :

```
 obs1 = obs1.map(new Func1<Integer, Integer>() {
        public Integer call(Integer integer) {
         try {
                getObj().equals(""); // an exception occurs
                return ++integer;
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                throw OnErrorThrowable.addValueAsLastCause(t, integer);
            }
        }
    });
```